# Uploading gatling report to s3

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, kubernetes, amazon-eks, gatling

I'm running some stresses tests in cluster. I compile Gatling code in a jar and run it in a dockerized environment. Likewise, I was wondering if there is a way to upload the final Gatling report to S3. There is `after` hook in Gatling simulation class, but I think this is getting executed before the report is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way I can think to do this without changing even the gatling code or the jar, is to simply:

- Make the docker container running the tests run as an init container
- After the init container had run, a main container starts and can do the s3 upload, either with bash commands or with whatever (example, with tinys3 - https://github.com/smore-inc/tinys3 )

Just a general example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: gatling-stress-test
    app.kubernetes.io/name: gatling-stress-test
  name: gatling-stress-test
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: gatling-stress-test-runner
    image: gatling-docker-image:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /full/path/to/gatling/reports
      name: reports
  containers:
  - name: stress-test-s3-copier
    image: ubuntu-image-with-tinys3:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /full/path/to/gatling/reports
      name: reports
  volumes:
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: reports
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately it might not work in my case. Actually I'm having some other containers in pod also which act as services against which Gatling is performing the stress test.

Comment: In that case, if you want to keep things separated, you could create yet another container which watches the volume, waiting for reports to be available.. then it uploads them on s3. It's mostly similar.. except more complex.

Comment: I separated the containers in different pods, and I'm using a watch container to monitor the report file.